# Textarea not appearing on second page through php

Tags: php

When I click on the "CREATE" button, the .php page opens, but what I want to appear as regular text, does not appear at all.

First page/.html

```
<body>
        <form id="username" action="Post.php" method="post">
            <div class="username">
                <input type="text" form="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="username" name="username">
            </div>
        </form>
        <form id="postarea" action="Post.php" method="post">
                <div class="text" align="center">
                    <textarea  name="postarea" form="postarea" class="text" id="postarea" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="Write your post here"></textarea>
                </div>
            <button class="button" type="sumbit">CREATE</button>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Second Page/post.php

```
<body>
        <?php
            echo $_POST["username"]
            echo $_POST["postarea"];
        ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: Dont use GET, use POST. Form `method="post"` and `$_POST['fieldname']`... GET adds to the url.

Comment: you also have another typo type="sumbit" in `<button class="button" type="sumbit">CREATE</button>`

Comment: You have a typo on line 3 in post.php. Missing a `;`.

Answer (score 1):

@incredibleHat has reason

Change your code as follow

First page:

```
<body>
<form id="formPostArea" action="post.php" method="post">
  <div class="username">
    <input type="text" form="formPostArea" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="text" align="center">
    <textarea name="postarea" form="formPostArea" class="text" id="postarea" cols="60" rows="15"
              placeholder="Write your post here"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="CREATE"/>
</form>
</body>
```

File post.php

```
<body>
    <?php
        echo $_POST['username'];
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $_POST['postarea'];
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: This has removed what is entered from appearing in the URL but it does not show what is entered in the 'textarea' does not appear on the second page.

Comment: I were testing the solution and its working in my local environment

Comment: I have edited my code by copying your code, above, but the input into the textarea still does not appear on the second page. Can you suggest any reasons for this? To clarify this is meant to work publicly, unsure if this changes anything.

Comment: Do you need a second page with a textarea with entered text on the first page or only display text entered on the first page?

Comment: Please test again, if you have any message error please post else debug with a browser console (Maybe Chrome https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) and review Console and Network tabs

Comment: Ideally, only display text.

Comment: @H.Greenwood is it Works with the last modification?

Answer (score 0):

Erase `type="text"` from the `textarea` tag

Comment: I have removed the type="text" from the area tag, as seen above, but i still does not appear on the .php page.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following and it works for me

PHP

```
<?php

echo $_POST["username"];
echo $_POST["postarea"];

?>
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="username" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="username">
            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="username" name="username">
        </div>

        <div class="text" align="center">
            <textarea name="postarea" class="text" id="postarea" cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="Write your post here"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="button" type="sumbit">CREATE</button>
    </form>
</body>
```